# Report Builder 2016 freezes, SQL Server 2016 RC 3.3 and VS 2015 installed

Tags: report, builder

Using Report Builder 2016 after creating the Data source the program freezes.
On my computer I have installed SQL Server 2016 RC 3.3 and VS Community 2015 w/ SSDT

Tried to create a blank report adding in the Data source and query, when trying to preview the report I get an error.

The definition of this report is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services. The report definition may have been created with a later version of Reporting Services, or contain content that is not well-formed or not valid based on Reporting Services schemas. Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.